# How do we identify if an opportunity or Lead has a pending or overdue task

Tags: apex, tasks

I need to know if an opportunity or Lead has any pending or Overdue tasks?

I can search for opportunity or Lead in WhatId of task and get all the records for this ID. How do i know if a task is overdue or pending? Which field should i refer on task to identify this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to query these records using soql? if so the query would be something like

```
List<Task> leadOverdueTasks = [SELECT Id, ActivityDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :leadIds AND ActivityDate <= :Date.today()];
```

The important thing being you are searching for a Due Date (api name for due date is ActivityDate) before or on today.

**Edit**

Logic for pending tasks: WHERE IsClosed = false AND currentdate <= ActivityDate

Logic for overdue tasks: WHERE IsClosed = false AND currentdate > ActivityDate

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Just to confirm a task would be overdue if the currentdate > ActivityDate and it would be pending if the currentdate <= ActivityDate and isClosed = false

Comment: @Prady just added the logic into the answer for you